# Fix series order

Tags: dimple.js

I am producing a graph using the following code:

```
var svg = dimple.newSvg("#p_m", 1200, 200+(data.f_c_c*20));
var chrt_participants = new dimple.chart(svg, data.result);
chrt_participants.setBounds(200, 50, 900, 100+(data.f_c_c*20));
var y = chrt_participants.addCategoryAxis("y", ["title", "name"]);
var x = chrt_participants.addLogAxis("x", "Activity");
var s = chrt_participants.addSeries(["cid_id","cid","action"], dimple.plot.bar);
chrt_participants.addLegend(800, 0, 400, 40, "left");
chrt_participants.draw();
```

It draws the following graph:

[image: Example chart]
Everything is as expected, except that the series (the coloured chunks of the bars) don't seem to be put in any particular order. As you can see, for two bars, for some reason unbeknownst to me, the red value is placed before the blue.

Is there a way to fix the order of the series?

Answer (score 1):

The default order is descending by value but you can easily override using series.addOrderRule(). The documentation explains how:

https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/wiki/dimple.series#addOrderRule

On a side issue, be careful using a log axis for a stacked bar, it's very misleading. It's not immediately apparent that red and blue have about a 50/50 split of bars. You might be better using a grouped bar instead so that both categories receive comparable scaling.

Comment: John, Thanks for your suggestion. I looked into that, and it works great if you only have one series, as I have three, and want to set the order (colour) for the third series, that's where it gets a little difficult. Any suggestion on how I can override the order for the third series ("action")?
`var s = chrt_participants.addSeries(["cid_id","cid","action"], dimple.plot.bar);`